# Authentication django

Tags: python, html, css, django

Why is `self.request.user.is_authenticated()` not working in this view?

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView, CategoryListMixin):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'mainapp/article_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = self.model.objects.all()
        context['article'] = self.get_object()
        context['comments'] = Comments.objects.filter(article=context['article']).order_by('-pub_date')
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            context['current_user'] = PersonalAccount.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

I got an error:

> 'bool' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Django 1.10 +**

is_authenticated is now an attribute.

```
if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue. if works then accept the answer